# Handle sequential HTTP calls with the same message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I would like to make two sequential calls one after the other, but using the same request message for both calls. But as shown in my sample code, the response from the first post call becomes the request of the second call by default. What is the most elegant solution for this pattern in spring integration

```
 public IntegrationFlow test() {
   return IntegrationFlows
       .from("testChannel")
       .handle(httpConfigurations.postCall1())
       .handle(httpConfigurations.postCall2())
       .get();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the first `.handle` add a header enricher with an expression to copy the `payload` to a header.

Before the second `.handle` use a `.transform()` to copy the header back to the payload.

Comment: You also can use a `publishSubscribeChannel()` with both those `handle()` as `subscribe()` sub-flows.

Comment: @Artem Bilan, I think the publishsubscribeChannel() would not do the calls in a sequential manner!

Comment: Without an `executor` (by default) it does. Please, see it’s source code if you are still in a doubt